# A continuous map in a subset of the complex projective space.

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

Consider the function
$$
h:V_{i}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow V_{i}\\
([z],t) \mapsto [z_{0}:\ldots:tz_{i}:\ldots:z_{n}]
$$
  where $V_i=\mathbb{C}P^n\backslash\{0\}$.
I want to prove that this function is continuous. I first thought that I could just write $h$ as a composition of the quotient map, a map in $V_i$ and the inverse of the quotient map. Something like this:

$$
h([z],t)=[z_{0}:\ldots:tz_{i}:\ldots:z_{n}]=\left(q_{n}\circ\alpha_{t}\circ q_{n}^{-1}\right)\left([z_{0}:\ldots:z_{i}:\ldots:z_{n}]\right)
 $$
But this seems fishy: I am not sure of the continuity of $q^{-1}$ and I have "hidden" the variable $t$ in $\alpha$ (and I do not know if I can do it).

Comment: Inverse of the quotient map is not a function. You can cover $P^n$ by chart, compute your function in each of the chart and check that it's continuous.

Comment: @N.H. Of course it is not a function... Thanks.
I do not see what that "chart" method is: shouldn't continuity depend only on the topology (and not on the differential structure)?

Comment: There are also charts for topological manifolds. If you prefer, it's enough to verify that $h_{|U_j}$ is continuous for all $j$, since $U_j$ cover $P^n$. And here you can use the homeomorphism $U_j \cong \mathbb C^n$.